# How can I create zoom 'windows' showing a zoomed portion of an image based on a div location using CSS3/HTML5 or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a non-rectangular cropping tool right now where I would like to have a zoomed view for each crop point. In the example image below, the crop points are the corner of the squares connected by the red lines.

[Early polygonal crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7bpF.jpg)

Those squares are draggable div's created by [JSPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html). These div's look like this:

```
<div id="bottomRight" class="item _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_ ui-draggable" style="top:
335.3999938964844px; left: 549px;">
</div>
```

I would like four zoom windows around the image, where I can see a zoomed-in view of each corner, but I can only find resources on doing zooms around the mouse. Ideally, these views would be same-sized squares centered at the current location of the jsPlumb endpoint.

I found the CSS Zoom attribute, but it seems it is very depreceated. I know that the answer probably lies somewhere in css3's transform.scale property, but I don't know how to proceed. While I would prefer a css/html solution, I am by no means opposed to using some JS to get the job done. Any tips or insights are appreciated!

Comment: It's been a while since you asked this, but do you want to zoom to occur on hovering over the endpoints or by clicking on them?

Comment: Neither. I would like the zoom to be always on. The crop lines connect to a square that serves as a handle at a point (see above image). I would like four 'zoom boxes' surrounding the four corners of the image that is being cropped, which are always zoomed in/centered on the corner of the crop handles (the squares the lines are attached to). That way, you can get a zoomed-in view of exactly where you are cropping.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that it is possible with *only* css, ie. I think, you will need some Jquery (or javascript), and I hope I understood your question:

I would just put a div with class 'zoom-container' on the page, that holds the zoomed and shifted image.

I think for the matrix() in transform: you will need to change the values per JavaScript.

here is a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HE7hz/5/) 
and the code:

```
<img src='http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/cute_puppy_photo_picture_11_168839.jpg' />
<div class='zoom-container'>
    <img src='http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/cute_puppy_photo_picture_11_168839.jpg'  class='zoom-center' />
<div>
```

css:

```
div.zoom-container {
    position:absolute; 
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img.zoom-center {
    -webkit-transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,-200,-200 ); //(:edit) 
    transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,-200,-200 );
}
```

Tell me if I understood you question anf feel free to ask for help with the jquery part